# smooth-scrolling jquery no method

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to use the **smoothDivScroll** plugin on my website, as I have no understanding of jQuery, I've just copied and pasted everything. The first image loads, and the hotspots show up, but the scrolling never starts and I don't see any other images.

I am using the google API's library plus the 3 jQuery files from the plugin

And here is the page on my website where I'm trying to implement it:
http://www.belindabilly.com/shop/belindabilly.html

On line 16, where the javascript is, I keep getting this error message:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object, Object] has no method "smoothDivScroll"

I've looked through all of the files and can't really make heads or tails of it. I've also google searched the object error, but all I can figure out is that somewhere in all of the code, something is either missing, or loading twice. Like I said, I've copied and pasted from the examples on http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/index.html, so I don't see how I could have messed it up so badly!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, I made several mistakes, but the biggest one was that I did not include the script for the mousewheel. The way it made it look on the site, and in the source code of other sites that used previous versions, was that jQuery mousewheel was optional. IT'S NOT! Also, I may have ordered the scripts incorrectly.